# How can I get a program to run before the system process is started?

Tags: windows-7, boot

I am going to write a boot time program which will delete some configuration files and replace them with some of my own. The only problem is is that these files are in use by the system process.

1. Is this even possible?
2. How can I get the program to run before the system process is started?
3. What language would I need to write my program in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in windows, you encouter this any time a program ask to reboot windows after installing/uninstalling. I could not find the link for windows 7 but [this may get you started on the right path](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181345) on how to replace a in-use file at reboot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something before the system loads, you will have to do it when the system is offline (through a different host OS). It does not matter what language you code this in.